# Show that the binomial series satisfies: $(1+x)f'(x)=\alpha f(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

If $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\alpha\choose n}x^n$, show (without assuming the results of the binomial theorem) that
$$(1+x)f'(x)=\alpha f(x)$$ for $|x|<1$

I've already shown that the sum converges, but I have no idea how to manipulate it to get that $\alpha$ in front of the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$$\begin{align}&f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom\alpha n x^n\\{}\\
&f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom\alpha n nx^{n-1}\end{align}$$

Perhaps the trick you're looking for is

$$n\binom\alpha n=\alpha\binom{\alpha-1}{n-1}$$

**Added on request:** $$\alpha f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha\binom\alpha nx^n=\alpha\binom\alpha0+\alpha\binom\alpha1x+\alpha\binom\alpha2x^2+\ldots$$

OTOH:

$$(1+x)f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\binom \alpha nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\binom\alpha nx^n=$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\binom\alpha nx^{n-1}(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha\binom{\alpha-1}{n-1}x^{n-1}(1+x)=$$

$$=\alpha\binom{\alpha-1}0(1+x)+\alpha\binom{\alpha-1}1x(1+x)+\alpha\binom{\alpha-1}2x^2(1+x)+\ldots$$

Well, now just compare coefficients of corresponding powers of $\;x\;$ in both expressions: they are equal.

Comment: @user84413 I suppose Timbuc means $$n \binom{\alpha}{n} = \alpha \binom{\alpha-1}{n-1} \; .$$

Comment: @aexl Thanks - that makes sense.

Comment: I edited your answer to change the last binomial, but please correct it if I have made a mistake.

Comment: @user84413 It''s. fine. Thank you.

Comment: I'm still stuck. How do I raise $x$ to degree $n$?

Comment: @moni94 I added some stuff. you'll have probably to use some induction for the last part, but if you do the comparison between coefficients of $\;x^0\,,\,x\,,\,x^2\;$ , etc. , you'll see what is there.